# Search service application error in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, searchserviceapplication

I want to configure search service application in SharePoint 2013.

When i go to CA > manage services is shows below view.

On the place of started or stopped  it shows 'error'. I'm using admin credentials here.

[image]

When I click on that search service application, it shows below details.

[image]

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by going through the below links.

[link1](http://expertsharepoint.blogspot.de/2014/07/the-search-service-is-not-able-to_19.html)

[link2](http://expertsharepoint.blogspot.de/2014/07/the-search-service-is-not-able-to.html)